# mysql update table where null

Tags: php, mysql

Hello have spent many hours looking for either a tutorial or answer to my update query. It is for a time tracking system

Table is like

```
| id | emp_nr | start_time          | end_time |

|  1 |    47  | 2018-01-31 13:15:10 |  NULL    |
```

This query works for the update, but needs help because it will update regardless
because it is within the same day and not move to a new field or return an error.

```
UPDATE time SET end_time='$date' 
WHERE  DATE(`start_time`) = CURDATE() AND `emp_nr`=$emp_nr";
```

I want to update the end_time field with the current time only if it is NULL and within the last 12 hours. If a date change happens then it will not update at all and return a value of " ".

I am seeking some advice here and am a bit confused. I have done some reading on "ON Duplicate Key" or should the update query be more in the direction of an "IF/THEN/ELSE"?

Comment: For MySQL you can add something like `and end_time is null` to your where clause.

Comment: you need to add an additional clause.

Comment: can you describe this condition If a date change happens then it will not update at all and return a value of " ";

Comment: last 12 hours or last 24?

Comment: You can do one thing to check `end_time ` is null or not. First of all get the row with `emp_nr` check through php if it is null update the date otherwise skip query. Thats it.

Comment: Using PHP would be great, a short example or a link to read up on the correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more column in where clause for check end_time IS NULL.
For example-

```
UPDATE time SET end_time='$date' 
    WHERE  DATE(`start_time`) = CURDATE() AND `emp_nr`=$emp_nr 
       AND end_time IS NULL";
```

Comment: Adding the "AND end_time IS NULL" filled in all of the NULL fields with the CURDATE, even those where the date was more that two days old. Is there a way to limit the time to the last 12 or 15 hours?

Comment: Try this-
UPDATE time SET end_time='$date' 
    WHERE  DATE(`start_time`) = CURDATE() AND `emp_nr`=$emp_nr 
       AND ( end_time IS NULL OR end_time >= DATE_SUB(NOW( ),INTERVAL 12 HOUR) )";

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
UPDATE time SET end_time='$date' 
WHERE  DATE(`start_time`) = CURDATE() AND `emp_nr`=$emp_nr AND end_time IS NULL;
```

Comment: Need to remove the quote after `=$emp_nr`